# How to overwrite plugin config in module from parent's profile in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have project with parent pom and module. Within parent pom I have declared few profiles:

```
   <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profileone</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
            ...
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>profiletwo</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- Here is plugin a -->
                </plugin>
                    <!-- Here I want to change value in configuration in plugin b from module -->
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

I have also pom for module

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>plugin-b</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>value-a</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Now all of my profiles make use of the same module but `profiletwo` add `plugin a` and need to overwrite value in configuration of module's `plugin b`. How can I achieve that?